# How do I convert synchronous ajax to asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, coffeescript

**What I am trying to accomplish**

I am trying to check the server time and compare it against preset closing time to prevent user from clicking on expired sale items (and display the item has expired) but I am hitting a snag on how to accomplish this when it's mixed in with synchronous call

I know async:false is a very bad idea and it won't work in Firefox(works in Chrome and IE) but it does exactly what I wanted.  I am having a hard time figuring out how to convert my code to be asynchronous.  If I change part of my code asynchronous then all my other parts of code that depends on it falls apart because the timing is off.

**Previous Code** - All I would call if sale_closed()

```
@get_server_time: (url) ->
$.ajax(
  url: url + '/servertime'
  type: 'GET'
  async: false
)

@sale_closed: () ->
   if not @is_valid_user
     return true
   if Config.override_bid_closed?
     return false
   if @get_server_time(url) > sale_end
     return true
   return false
```

What I tried to do but that's not working

**CoffeeScript**

```
@get_server_time: (url) ->
$.ajax(
  url: url + '/servertime'
  type: 'GET'
)

@sale_closed: () ->
  @get_server_time(url).done (data) ->
   if not @is_valid_user
     return true
   if Config.override_bid_closed?
    return false
   if data > sale_end
     return true
   return false
```

Same code in

**Javascript:**

```
function get_server_time (url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url + '/servertime',
    type: 'GET'
  });
};

function sale_closed() {
    get_server_time(url).done(function(data) {
     if (!this.is_valid_user()) {
      return true;
    }
    if (Config.override_sale_closed != null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (data > sale_end) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
};
```

**Is this correct?**

Is the expectation to change all my sale_close code from

```
foo: () ->
  if sale_closed()
    /* do something */
```

to

```
do_something: () ->
 /* do something */

foo: () - >
  sale_closed(do_something)
```

That's a giant nightmare because I have to change a lot of code and would make them all asynchronous which may break all other functions that call 'foo', 'foo2', etc. (which were synchronous before).

Is there anything guarantee the variables do_something read will be in context and have the same value when it execute?

Thanks for your help as I try to wrap my head around this

---

Comment: if you want async code, then you need to have callbacks that can be triggered when the ajax call DOES finish/returns. those callbacks are how you link the various stages together. a) send data to server b) main code goes elsewhere c) when ajax call returns, callback fires up and starts doing whatever it has to

Comment: Unroll `@sale_closed` to look more like `@sale_closed: (callback) -> ...` and say `callback(whatever)` instead of `return whatever` inside `@sale_closed`. Then turn the `sale_closed` caller inside-out.

Comment: It's not so much I want async code it's that Firefox doesn't support async: false due to their strict enforcement on CORS (base on what I am reading on bugzilla and on here) so that means I have to rewrite my code to work with async.

Are you two saying what I described in **Is this correct** section?  I just want to be sure I understood it correct because that would mean I have stuff all my current code that comes after `if @saled_closed` into a function that accepts `(whatever)`  rather than just changing `@sale_closed` function I have to change all code that called on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this correct?

Not really. You cannot `return` from asynchronous callbacks as like as you would in synchronous code. Instead, you will want to use Promises:

```
@get_server_time: (url) ->
  $.ajax(
    url: url + '/servertime'
    type: 'GET'
  )

@sale_closed: () ->
  if not @is_valid_user
    return $.when true
  if Config.override_bid_closed?
    return $.when false
  @get_server_time(url).then (data) ->
    data > sale_end
```

> Is the expectation to change all my code that calls sale_close?

Yes, you will need to change everything to callback style. With promises, the changes won't be very large though, and the flow stays linear.

> Is there anything guarantee the variables do_something read will be in context and have the same value when it execute?

You should declare `do_something` locally inside the `foo` function (or just use a function expression), which will guarantee that all the variables you need are in scope. If you need the right `this` context, use fat arrow functions.

Comment: actually, i wouldn't recommend using promises to a user who is confused over asynchronicity—they tend to add another layer of indirection and are, in my experience, not worth while. the important thing to understand here is YES, your premonition is right, you WILL have to change a lot of code. tough luck, but a single asynchronous function does mean all of your program now is asynchronous. a great device and very contagious. i do get the impression the OP does and relies too much on the browser. Know that whatever business logic you do on client side a malicious client may fake.

Comment: Thank you both for confirming my worst fear.  I am more used to server side scripting + light javascript but this new project I inherited doesn't allow that luxury.  It just amaze me that a simple server time that I was able to do with one line code before and now has turned into a giant monster.

Looks like I will have to go another way to fake the server time

Answer (score 0):

Try doing some logging and if the problem is that you don't have access to the function `@is_valid_user` then try changing this

```
  @get_server_time(url).done (data) ->
```

to this

```
  @get_server_time(url).done (data) =>
```

the fat arrow binds the callback function on done to the current context of `this` therefore preserving the ability to call `this.is_valid_user`. Hard to tell exactly if this will work for you without a larger code context, but I might try that first.